# PHP not performing

Tags: php

This one may take a little but please stay with me for it.

I have been working with this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['o']) && isset($_GET['q'])){
    echo("WIN 1");
    if($_GET['o'] == "remove") {
        echo("WIN 2");
        $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']]-=1;
        echo("WIN 3");
        if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']] < 1) {
            unset($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']]);
            echo("WIN 4");
            redirect("checkout.php");
        } else {
            echo("LOSE");
            redirect("checkout.php");
        }
    }
}
```

And it is not performing any of the functions unless I step through it using:

```
exit();
```

After each of the echos.
I have no idea what could be causing this issue.

The URL being passed is:

```
localhost/cart.php?q=1&o=remove
```

Thank you!

EDIT

This is how I set the session (I have removed the echos):

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
        $query = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id=".escape_string($_GET['q'])."");
        confirm($query);
        while($row = fetch_array($query)){
            if($row['product_quantity'] != $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']]){
                $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']]+=1;
                redirect("checkout.php");
            } else if($row['product_quantity_tracking'] == "No") {  //CHECK TO SEE IF IT'S INVENTORY TRACKED
                redirect("checkout.php");
            } else {
                set_message("Sorry! There isn't enough in stock to complete that request!");
                redirect("checkout.php");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the redirect function:

```
function redirect($location){
    header("Location: $location");
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: i think session product is empty

Comment: What seems to be the problem and what is your issue. please provide some details about your issue or error as it's not clear in your question.

Comment: the problem is -= 1 , session is not initialized the product_ + id , your substracting NULL - 1 , It will throw an error, undefined index

Comment: @Jerson, Session is set fine, you cannot get to this page without having the session variable set.

Comment: @TufailAhmad I would gladly provide more detail but there are no more details that I can get from the problem, this is why I am having to ask on here :(

Comment: What is the value of $_SESSION['product_1'].  before executing this code? You can echo it and check the value whether it's integer or not

Comment: @TufailAhmad the value of $_SESSION['product_1'] is indeed an INT as it is parsed through intval before it is handed to the session details.

Comment: Did you use session_start(); somewhere?

Comment: @Martin yes I have been. All my other session variables work. I can add to the $_SESSION['product_1'] count, it just won't remove anything from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for some reason, when I hit the redirect on the `cart.php` it was running the REST OF THE PAGE instead of just redirecting and exiting the page as it would be expected to do.

For me to have solved this issue, I had to change the code to the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['o']) && isset($_GET['q'])){
    if($_GET['o'] == "remove") {
        $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']]-=1;
        if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']] < 1) {
            unset($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['q']]);
            redirect("checkout.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            redirect("checkout.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

By adding the `exit();` after the redirects it made sure it didn't follow the rest of the script on the page.

Thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

By using `exit();` you stop the execution of your script and you can see everything that was printed out using your `echo`s.

-> If you can the see something like 'WIN 1', 'WIN 2', ... when exiting your script, it is working fine **until this line**.

-> Your problem must be found after this line.

I guess your problem lies in the `redirect()` function.
See this for how to perform a redirect: [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: I have the `redirect()` code as a function using headers in a seperate file. And that isn't an issue.
What is an issue is if I step through the function it works fine. But if I let it run through as intended, it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, can you please show how you set the session and the redirect function?

Comment: I have updated the question with the redirect and session functions